# CSS bold not working properly when font is SegoeUI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fonts

```
<div style={{ fontFamily: 'SegoeUI' }}>
  <b>Hello world</b>
</div>
```

Whenever I set the font to `SegoeUI`, both the `<strong>` and `<b>` tags are not working. If I remove the font, they work perfectly. Any ideas why is this so and how can I fix this?

Comment: it seems to work perfectly for me. (maybe the font that you are importing doesn't have a bold one inside it.)
check codepen
https://codepen.io/parthmakadiya12-the-flexboxer/pen/GREbEoy

Comment: Hm, kind of weird. Same code, doesn't work in my case. Thanks anyway, I thought that the problem is somewhere in the font itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="font-family:'SegoeUI'">
            <b>Hello world</b>
        </div>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work since I use React.

Comment: If you answer a question: explain it. don't just say "try this".

Comment: maybe u did not install a bold version of SegoeUI front, Its working for me, so I said try this, he did not ask for an explanation :)

Answer (score -1):

First check if the SegoeUI bold .ttf file is added or not.

If yes, then use `style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}`.

Comment: Don't post comments as answers!

Answer (score -1):

If it is still not working, you can define the text properties globally and import them.

```
.font-type { 
 font-family: 'SegoeUI', bold; 
}
```

Comment: Don't post comments as answers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).